# Apache Tomcat throws errors when uploaded App

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat

I am currently trying to run my REST service on a local Apache Tomcat7. When I access `localhost:8080` everything works fine. If I compile my app using `maven clean install`, copy the resulting *.war file to `cp target/myapp.war /var/lib/tomcat7/webapp` and restart Tomcat using `systemctl restart tomcat7`, I can use my app as expected by accessing `localhost:8080/myapp/rest/myservice`. However, if now try to access `localhost:8080`, I get a HTTP 500 error. A look into the server logs gives me the below stacktrace. What's the reason for this error and how can I fix it. As I said the App works fine.

```
Mar 31 19:17:01 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: Mar 31, 2014 7:17:01 PM org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl internalGetPageContext
                                       SEVERE: Exception initializing page context
                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/StaticFieldELResolver
                                               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalGetPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:172)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:123)
                                               at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:52)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                                               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
                                               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFi
Mar 31 19:17:01 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: lter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                                               at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
                                       INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 31 19:16:57 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: Mar 31, 2014 7:16:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
                                       INFO: Server startup in 4257 ms
Mar 31 19:17:01 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: Mar 31, 2014 7:17:01 PM org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl internalGetPageContext
                                       SEVERE: Exception initializing page context
                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/StaticFieldELResolver
                                               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.internalGetPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:172)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.getPageContext(JspFactoryImpl.java:123)
                                               at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:52)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                                               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
                                               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFi
Mar 31 19:17:01 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: lter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                                               at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
                                               at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
                                               at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProto
Mar 31 19:17:01 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: col$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
                                               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2378)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.StaticFieldELResolver
                                               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
                                               ... 27 more
Mar 31 19:17:01 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: Mar 31, 2014 7:17:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
                                       SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerE
                                       java.lang.NullPointerException
                                               at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:55)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
                                               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
                                               at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
                                               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                                               at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFil
Mar 31 19:17:01 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: ter.java:52)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
                                               at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
                                               at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
                                               at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
                                               at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprE
Mar 31 19:17:01 azlan jsvc.exec[7451]: ndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2378)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**// UPDATE //**

I had a look into the Resteasy manual as suggested and updated my web.xml. However, if I now access my service at `localhost:8080/spozz/users`, I get the expected result. but if I access `localhost:8080/spozz/` I do not see my `index.html` anymore.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>The SpoZZ Webservice</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>net.avedo.spozz.Spozz</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: What bindings do you have for "/"?

Comment: This looks like the real problem:                                        `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException` It's trying to map "/" to some controller, but you don't have one defined.

Comment: This is my first web service, so I am not sure what you mean, but I assume that this has something to do with my configuration in `web.xml`!? So I added it to my initial post.